# Options Menu in Action Bar Displays option too high up

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin

I want the menu that pops up after clicking the vertical three dots to display the menu starting below the Action bar, not in line with it as shown in this picture. How can I do this?

Default Options Menu:

[image]

Expected positioning of the Options Menu:

[image]

Here is my code in the Activity:

```
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.channelmenu, menu)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle presses on the action bar menu items
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.logoutButton -> {
                logoutClick()
                return true
            }
            else -> {
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
            }
        }
    }
```

Code in the Layout:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.treechat.ChannelListActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/logoutButton"
        android:title="Logout"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/item2"
        android:title="Item 2"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `actionOverflowMenuStyle` and put a custom style inside `AppTheme` in `styles.xml` like this, where you'll turn `overlapAnchor` to `false` and set an offset for it:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/OptionsMenuCustomStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="OptionsMenuCustomStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">
    <item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>
    <item name="android:overlapAnchor" tools:ignore="NewApi">false</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">4.0dip</item>
</style>
```

The out would look exactly like your requirement:

[image]